# What files are needed to publish a web service created by eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I've created a web service using eclipse wizard using CXF, what files and modifications are necessary to port the same web service to another project? because I'm not sure what all was modified on my existing project to create it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files and modifications depends on the version of CXF used and the the additional libraries used.  Mostly the following are configurations to enable cxf

1. The Apache CXF Endpoint Servlet definition and mapping in web.xml
2. beans.xml bean definition file (in WEB-INF) if you are using spring as IoC with CXF, and related spring context loader listener definition in web.xml

There are lots of additional jar files to go with including the cxf jars and dependencies, but this all depends on what all functionalities you are using.

Comment: im using CXF 2.5.2, right now my problem is different, I can't even use it on the same project